# MYSQL join return too many results

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

So I'm trying to get some total numbers of different tables in the database.
This is the query that I'm using

```
$this->db->select('
        c.*,
        SUM(rm.discount_value) as totalDiscount,
        SUM(a.status = 0) as totalVisits,
        SUM(a.status != 0) as totalAnnulations,
        SUM(r.treatment_price + r.arrangement_price + r.product_price) + c.start_rev as totalRevenue
    ')
        ->join('customers c','c.customer_id = a.customer_id','left')
        ->join('revenue r','r.customer_id = a.customer_id','left')
        ->join('remarks rm','rm.customer_id = a.customer_id','left')
        ->from('agenda a')
        ->where('a.user_id',$user_id)
        ->where('a.customer_id',$customer_id)
        ->group_by('a.customer_id');
```

This results in the following query.

```
SELECT `c`.*, 
       SUM(rm.discount_value) as totalDiscount,
       SUM(a.status = 0) as totalVisits, SUM(a.status != 0) as totalAnnulations, 
       SUM(r.treatment_price + r.arrangement_price + r.product_price) + c.start_rev as totalRevenue 
FROM (`agenda` a) 
       LEFT JOIN `customers` c ON `c`.`customer_id` = `a`.`customer_id`
       LEFT JOIN `revenue` r ON `r`.`customer_id` = `a`.`customer_id`
       LEFT JOIN `remarks` rm ON `rm`.`customer_id` = `a`.`customer_id` WHERE `a`.`user_id` = '9' AND `a`.`customer_id` = '4134' 
       GROUP BY `a`.`customer_id`
```

This query is returning **4810** visits, but there are only **74**.

This returns too many results. Its like its not using that a.customer_id

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some data sample and result you have vs expected result please?

Comment: I've added some more info. If u need more just let me know

Comment: You select c and group by a. That's a little weird.

Comment: Forget about the Laravel for now, and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You did not provide anything I did ask for. I've asked about "actual data", "actual results" and expected result SAMPLE based on "actual data" you provide

Comment: most likely because of your sum, try having a select sum instead of directly summing the values, something among the lines:  (select SUM(rm.discount_value) from remarks rm where rm.id = remarks.id) as totalDiscount .      where remarks.id is your table on the upper query

Comment: @Strawberry : Does not make a difference if I use a or c.

Alex : It simply returns a row, username,firstname,lastname,visits,revenue....
I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for. I cant simply paste raw results here because the data is actually beeing used in production. Only the field names are different there

Comment: @ZenelShabani move `->from('agenda a')` next to select and check

Comment: @abr I'm still editing it, but I think thats the right way to do it. I'll keep u updated :)

Comment: @Dead Man , that did not do the trick :(

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense.  Maybe if you fix it, it will also resolve your problem.  Your query, by itself, is not a valid query.  It will error out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GROUP BY with a column that does not appear in the SELECT. See [how to use GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462163/group-by-functioning-in-sql/48462839#48462839).